# Ionic alert back button

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I create an email application, i work on the email creation.

I have a back button on the left part of my header page who go back to the mailing list, and in the right side i have multiple buttons, one of them is the rubbish, to delete the email who we are writing.

When we click on this icon, an ionic alert appear, the first button "Cancel" just go back on the email creation.
The "Yes delete" button have to go back on the mailing list, like the left back button.

How can i make this action, like the ionic-back-button

My HTML page :

```html
<ion-header class="ion-no-border">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <!-- Boutton Icon et text retour -->
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button text="Retour" icon="chevron-back-outline" class="ion-back-button"></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <!-- Icons fin de header -->
    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <!-- Boutton Icon gestion pièce jointe -->
      <ion-button color="primary" (click)="selectFile()"><ion-icon name="attach-outline" class="rotate-90 font-1_5rem"></ion-icon></ion-button>
      <!-- Boutton Icon d'envoie -->
      <ion-button type="submit" color="primary" (click)="sendEmail()" [disabled]="!emailForm.valid"><ion-icon name="send-outline"></ion-icon></ion-button>
      <!-- Boutton Icon enregistrement en brouillon -->
      <ion-button color="primary"><ion-icon name="document-outline"></ion-icon></ion-button>
      <!-- Boutton Icon de suppression-->
      <ion-button color="primary" (click)="showDelete()"><ion-icon name="trash-outline"></ion-icon></ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

My TS page :

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-email',
  templateUrl: './create-email.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-email.page.scss'],
})
export class CreateEmailPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(privates alertCtrl: AlertController){}
  
  async showDelete(){  
    await this.alertCtrl.create({
      header: "Supprimer le message ?",
      message: "Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer ce message ?",
      buttons: [
        {
          text: "Non, annuler"
        },
        {
          text: "Oui, supprimer", handler: (res) => {
            this.router.navigate
          }
        }
      ]
    }).then(res => res.present());
  }
  
}
```

Comment: this.router.navigate('whatever the path to mailing list page is');